# Concurrent AJAX callbacks: how to synchronize them?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, jsonp

My application loads *HTML* and *JavaScript* via *AJAX/JSONP* rather then loading pages by a standart way. It works in an *Iframe*, so, it's a right way to stay in communication with a parent *Frame* (*Safari* limitations).

I have to make 2 requests: to load *JavaScript* and *HTML* for a custom page. To be sure that all will be OK I can firstly load *JavaScript* then *HTML* (in *JavaScript* onload callback). But I would like these 2 request to be sent at the same time.

I prepared the code. The script must call **_finishLoading()** when both *JavaScript* and *HTML* have loaded. Is it possible the function **_finishLoading()** will not be executed in a browser?

```
 function Loader()
 {
       this.load = function()
       {
                    // ...some code here...

        var this_ = this;

        var jsLoaded = false;
        var htmlLoaded = false;

        $.ajax(
            url: newUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback:
                function()
                {
                    $.ajax(
                        url: someUrl,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success:
                            function( data )
                            {
                                $( '#' + contentElId ).html( data );

                                if( htmlLoaded )
                                {
                                    this_._finishLoading()
                                }

                                jsLoaded = true;
                            }
                    );
                }
        );

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: someUrl2,
                dataType: "html",
                success:
                    function( data )
                    {
                        $( '#' + contentElId ).html( data )

                        if( jsLoaded )
                        {
                            this_._finishLoading()
                        }

                        htmlLoaded = true;
                    }
            }
        );
    }
```

}

**Update**.

I need to load JavaScript, HTML then call onload() to init loaded Javascript. **If you know more convenient way then load them separetedly please let me know**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) function

The code would be something like this:

```
        var this_ = this;

        var jsLoaded = false;
        var htmlLoaded = false;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax(
            url: newUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback:
                function()
                {
                    $.ajax(
                        url: someUrl,
                        dataType: "html"
                        success: function(){
                           deferred.resolve();
                        }
                    );
                }
        );

        var promise2 = $.ajax(
            {
                url: someUrl2,
                dataType: "html",
            }
        );

        $.when(deferred, promise2).done(function(a1, a2){
           $( '#' + contentElId ).html(a1);
           $( '#' + contentElId ).html(a2);
           this_._finishLoading()
        });
```

Comment: I don't think that example works as written as `promise1` is undefined at the time $.when() is called. But it's the right idea, though I think you might need to create your own $.Deferred (so that it's valid for $.when()) and then pipe the inner $.ajax() to it.